# Check if a LinearLayout has a Clipped Child

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `Activity` that shows items as a list but I also need to be able to scroll horizontally through the items since they may overlay the screen to the right. To achieve that, I wrapped my container with a `HorizontalScrollView`.

I want to add my item to a container which is a vertical oriented `LinearLayout` programmatically, i.e. using `addView()` in a for loops. Since it's wrapped in a `HorizontalScrollView` as I mentioned earlier, it's impossible to the user to scroll vertically through the items so I need to make it paginated. Hope this illustration can gives you some better understanding.

[image: problem]

My problem is, how can I know if my container is *already full of items* on the recent page so I need to add the remaining items to the next page? I've checked if a view is clipped by using `View.GlobalVisibleRect(Rect r)` workaround as [How do I tell when an image is clipped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312865/how-do-i-tell-when-an-image-is-clipped) but still no luck. Thank you.

xml structure:

```
<HorizontalScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The programmatically added item views should goes here. -->

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: @Rahandi jalu is it ok to show the items in the next line if they are overflowing,

Comment: @war_Hero the items are more like a table with columns to the right so it needs to be in a single line

Comment: ok got it , why not use recyclerview, to do this?

Comment: @war_Hero I think wont since I want to avoid using adapters and I need to access individual item's view for advanced UI purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by using `View.getMeasuredHeight()` to measure the container layout's height then subtracts it also with the measured height of the item so the code will be like:

```
LinearLayout container = findViewById(R.id.container);

...

int rowHeight = 0;

container.measure(0,0);
int availableHeight = container.getMeasuredHeight();

while (availableHeight > rowHeight) {
    View toAdd = new View(this);

    ... // Do something with view and data

    container.addView(toAdd);

    toAdd.measure(0,0);
    rowHeight = toAdd.getMeasuredHeight();
    availableHeight -= rowHeight;
}
```